# React: Dynamically setting element keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tl;dr -- How do I dynamically add a `key` to a React Element?

---

I have a React component that, when standing alone, has a static list of children:

```
<componentA>
  <child ... />
  <child ... />
  <child ... />
</componentA>
```

As the list is static there are no keys on any of the children as they're not needed.

Now I have another component that wraps this one and makes it's children dynamic:

```
function componentB(componentA) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const filteredChildren = // ... filter this.props.children

      return (<componentA>
        {filteredChildren}
      </componentA>)
    }
  }
}
```

As the children are now dynamic I need to add `key`s to them, but if I try something like:

```
React.Children.map((child, i) => {
  child.key = i;
  return child
});
```

it fails saying `key` is readonly.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354086/react-cloneelement-not-setting-key) it seems that `cloneElement` is a no-go as well.  So is there a way to dynamically set a `key`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `cloneElement` inside `map` :

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child,  i) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { key:  i })
 );
```

Known that the 2ⁿᵈ argument of `React.cloneElement` is the NEW props of the cloned element . One of those props is the `key` in this example.

Comment: Thanks.  I misread the answer I linked, doh!  Will accept in a few min!

Comment: You are welcome. I just copy/paste from my React applications.. It is a long experience with React.

Comment: `key` is not assigned by React.cloneElement, it is ignored by the routine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so in your function, simply do this:

```
function componentB(componentA) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const filteredChildren = // ... filter this.props.children

      return (<componentA key={function_generating_random_strings()}>
        {filteredChildren}
      </componentA>)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only adds a key to the parent, I need a key on each child

Comment: @MarkKahn: see my answer , i think is enough